# what is the characteristic of $\mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

what is the characteristic of $\mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle $

I think it would be $0$ since I can't find any number of times that they can add to $0$. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The quotient is a field of characteristic $3$, since it contains the prime field $\mathbb{F}_3$. (The quotient *is* a field, because $x^3+2x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$).

Answer (score 1):

$3$ is in the kernel of the (unique) ring morphism $\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$ and $\mathbf{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$ is a field, so its characteristic is $3$.

Answer (score 0):

It's 3, the same characteristic as the base field $\Bbb Z_3$.